# php imagepng not working. shows question marks

Tags: php, gd2

I have following problem: imagepng, imagejpeg not working. I Got black question marks(unknown character list) on white screen. gd2 module is on.
for example take this simple code:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng($file_name);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im)
```

what i am missing?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("1.png");
ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: No it's png. Anyway I tried it on many images but still not result.

Comment: So no I tested it on different browsers and in IE works but chrome and firefox still question marks. have you idea why?

Comment: try it `ob_clean();header('Content-Type: image/png');`